# Constraint Satisfaction (Hierarchical) Solver

Tags: constraints, solver, linear-programming, hierarchical, constraint-programming

I need to model a constraint satisfaction (CSP) problem either in Java or .NET. The problem requires that a hierarchy of variables is represented. So every node of the tree is a variable.

For instance, if a variable C1 is a child of another variable C2 and if C1 is true than C2 should be true, because it is his parent. At the same time, if a variable node in a branch is true, this implies that all variables in other branches are false because there can be only one branch selected in the hierarchy.

### How can I represent it as a CSP problem and which tool can I use in Java or .NET?

I have to edit it to provide more details, because there are more than this:

In my problem there are 2 parts: In the 1st part, there is a  maximisation function q1*x1+q2*x2+q3*x3.. where qi is the coefficient (a real number) and xi is the variable (can be 0 or 1) and I have to select some of the xi which maximizes this function. In other words, nodes can only be 0 or 1 and I have to maximize this function by selecting a node from the hierarchy.

Again, these xi variables are the nodes of the tree, so when I select some xi, they have to be from the same branch of the tree and only 1 branch can be selected at a time. Therefore I need to represent these hierarchical constraints(2nd part). May be the best would be to represent everything as lp problem but I don't know how to represent a tree with linear programming constraints.

I don't know if at the same time I can use a maximisation problem (1st part) and impose CSP constraints (and not to use LP constraints).

Comment: Your "maximization problem" are the soft constraints and your "impose CSP constraints" are the hard constraints. A feasible solution has no hard constraints broken. An optimal solution is a feasible solution which maximizes the soft constraints. Most (if not all) CSP implementations will support hard and soft constraints (some support even more than just these 2 score levels).

Answer (score 1):

[Choco](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/) is a constraint solver that is implemented in Java and offers a Java API. It sounds like you want to use reified constraints in your model, that is constraints of the form

```
reify(otherConstraint(...), variable)
```

where `variable` becomes true or false depending on whether `otherConstraint` is satisfied or not. You can model the tree hierarchy by introducing auxiliary variables and adding reification constraints. Then you can link the auxiliary variables with a set of additional constraints to achieve effects such as you describe.

Alternatively, you could use simple conjunctions and disjunctions of constraints to model the tree -- whether this is possible will depend on the other constraints that determine the assignments to your variables.

Answer (score 1):

There is a number of solvers for constraint satisfaction problems (CSP) in Java. Here is an incomplete list:

- [JaCoP](http://jacop.osolpro.com/)
- [Choco](http://www.emn.fr/z-info/choco-solver/)
- [Cream](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/cream/)

That said, I think using a CSP solver is an overkill in your case unless you have some other constraints which you haven't mentioned. All you need is to treat your problem as a graph (tree?) with nodes corresponding to variables. Then taking a leaf node and going all the way up to the top setting variables along the way to true and setting all remaining variables to false will give you a solution. All you need for this is a graph library such as [JGraphT](http://jgrapht.org/)

Answer (score 0):

[Drools Planner](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html) (open source, java) [scales beyond](http://blog.athico.com/2012/07/scaling-planner-with-jit-selectors-in.html) the traditional CSP implementations and is also more flexible in score design (non-linear constraints, multiple score [weights](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3333) and [levels](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3354), ...) but doesn't recognize the optimal solution when it finds it.